# Click a custom button in lightning to redirect to a VF page in edit mode so that the case record type field can be edited

Tags: visualforce, lightning, edit

I have a custom button 'Convert to Quality case'. On click, it redirects to a VF page. I want to open the VF page in edit mode so that I can edit the 'Case record type' but I can't edit the Case record type field.

I have tried using this code in my VF page

```
<apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Action.MyObject__c.Edit, record.Id)}">
```

[image: this is the VF page that pops after clicking on Convert to Quality Case]

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a specific record type on the URL:

```
<apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Action.MyObject__c.Edit, record.Id, [RecordType='012XX00000XXXXX'])}">
```

The record type field is never directly editable, because it alters the page layout, picklist values, etc.

Comment: @GargiGupta it won't be editable; the record type must be selected before the edit page loads.

Comment: `<apex:page standardController="Case" extensions="SingleCase_Quality_BasePage_Controller" lightningStylesheets="true" >
       <apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Action.Case.Edit, record.Id, [RecordType='0126000000058u3AAA'])}"/>
    <apex:form >` I edited the code, still no luck.

Comment: Isn't the record type already selected? As when I click on the Convert To Quality button, it is redirecting to the VF page and it shows the 'Quality Management Case Record Type'.